# VB.NET Chart X-Axis not formatting properly

Tags: vb.net, charts

The code below employs 3 chart areas for making x-y scatter plots, and the x-axis values are successfully sorted in ascending order via the data manipulator.  However, the x-axis labels are not properly formatting to two decimal point precision.  Any suggestions?   I have successfully formatted both x- and y-axis before, but something is negating this feature(?)  [image: Image of Chart here]

```
Dim chart2 As New Chart
chart2.Invalidate()
chart2.ChartAreas.Clear()
chart2.Legends.Clear()
chart2.Series.Clear()
Chart2.Width = 400
chart2.Height = 800
chart2.Top = 30
Chart2.Left = 10
Chart2.Visible = True
Chart2.Enabled = True

Dim numvalidpoints As Integer = 0
Controls.Add(chart2)
For k = 1 To 3
    numvalidpoints = 10
    Cnt = -1
    Dim yValues(numvalidpoints - 1) As Double
    Dim xValues(numvalidpoints - 1) As String
    Dim delta As Single = 2 * Math.PI / numvalidpoints
    For j = 0 To numvalidpoints - 1
        Cnt += 1
        yValues(Cnt) = Rnd()
        xValues(Cnt) = yValues(Cnt)
    Next
    chart2.Series.Add(k - 1)
    chart2.Series(k - 1).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point '.Pie
    chart2.Series(k - 1).IsXValueIndexed = False
    chart2.Series(k - 1).Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues)
    chart2.ChartAreas.Add(k - 1)
    chart2.Series(k - 1).ChartArea = CStr(k - 1)
    'chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = True
    'chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = True
    'chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
    'chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = True
    chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.IsMarginVisible = False
    chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
    'chart2.Series(k - 1).Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending, "X")
    chart2.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending, "AxisLabel", k - 1)
    'Chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    'Chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    'Chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 75, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    'Chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 75, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
    chart2.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
Next k
'Chart2.Refresh()
'Chart2.Invalidate()
chart2.BringToFront()
```

Comment: You very much need to turn on `Option Strict` there are loads of implicit conversions going on

Comment: your xValues() array is of type string. N2 would work on a numeric conversion to string. I would try declaring your XValues as Decimal

Comment: Actually since you declare yValues as Double and then set xValues = yValues later on, then Declare xValues as Double. And follow Plutonix's advice and fix the implicit conversions. In most cases VS will offer a suggested fix. But at the very least, it will describe why it's detected as an error under Option Strict On.